# <a> element in an SVG doesn't work on Firefox and Safari

Tags: angularjs, firefox, svg, hyperlink, safari

I have an issue working on my SVG element for my website. My SVG is divided in different groups and i need each group to be a link to another page of my website (which is build with AngularJS). To make it clear: my SVG represents the world and for each region there's a link to a page. Here's a fragment of my SVG to show you how it tried to do the job:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 719.2 357.8">
    <a href="#!/resellers/?scrollTo=northamerica">
        <g id="northamerica">
            ....
```

as you can see i put each group into an  element. On Chrome it works perfectly, but when tested on Firefox or Safari it doesn't work, it looks like the link isn't there. Any suggestions on how to fix this? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need xlink:href rather than just href.

href without an xlink prefix is a new feature of the unfinished SVG 2 specification which has thus far only been implemented in Chrome. Support for bare href will be part of Firefox 51.

Comment: @LeonardoMinati what doe doesn't work mean? Doesn't load at all or isn't clickable. If you create an [mcve] I can see what's still wrong.

Comment: This should be the top answer.

Answer (score -1):

Actually I did the job using JQuery and $location.path(). Here's the code if someone need it:

```
$('.region').click(function() {
        var region = $(this).attr('data-region');
        switch (region) {
            case 'northamerica':
                $location.path('/resellers').search({
                    scrollTo: 'northamerica'
                });
                break;
            case 'southamerica':
                $location.path('/resellers').search({
                    scrollTo: 'southamerica'
                });
                break;
            case 'asia':
                $location.path('/resellers').search({
                    scrollTo: 'asia'
                });
                break;
            case 'africa':
                $location.path('/resellers').search({
                    scrollTo: 'africa'
                });
                break;
            case 'australia':
                $location.path('/resellers').search({
                    scrollTo: 'australia'
                });
                break;
            case 'europe':
                $location.path('/resellers').search({
                    scrollTo: 'europe'
                });
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    });
```

Just gave the .region class to each "g" tag and a data attribute. Maybe it's not the best solution, but for now it's the only one working.

If someone has a better working one, just post it! ;)

Comment: This breaks a lot of standard browser behaviour - you can no longer right click to open a new tab for example and you'll see weird behaviour if you middle click...